# Grunt Warning 6

Tags: gruntjs

Our automated build process incorporates a grunt task that periodically (more times than I'd like) generates a 6 return code.
According to the grunt web page 6 is a "Warning". Well okay, a warning for what? It's breaking our build since we would only pass on a 0 exit case. I'm looking at wrapping this in a script so I can catch this warning condition and generate a success exit code, though without any idea what the Warning might be I'm hesitant. It appears to work when I get this exit condition but would like a better understanding on what it may be.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So this turned out to be an issue with [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less). I didn't recognize the associated less compiler error in our build log:

```
[39mnon_object_property_loadError: Cannot read property 'rules' of undefined in ../../XXXX/styles/modules/SomeLessFile.less on line null, column 0: [31m
```

Once I found this line a google search quickly found [this in GitHub](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/166):

And have updated the grunt-contrib-less package. So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

check http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.fail:

> If --stack is specified on the command-line and an error object was
>   specified, a stack trace will be logged.

Or try to run "grunt --verbose --force"

Comment: Hey Bass, so I've added added '--verbose --stack' and when the process returns a 6, I see no verbose or stack output. Where should I find this?

Comment: Nix prior comment...  correct me if I'm wrong, but the grunt fail api is for the user to control grunt process on a non 0 exit process... I'd like to know why the warning 6 was issued in the first place and cannot find any diagnostic hook available that would provide this.

Comment: i expect that output in your console, but maybe i understand you wrong. If you do `grep -r "fail\.warn" node_modules` you should find which task sends a warning